# How to auto-sync photos on Android [replicate Samsung Cloud]

Tags: samsung, sync, cloud

On the Android phone Samsung Galaxy you can use Samsung Cloud which will sync your photos to online. Can we replicate this on a personal level to just your computer (and not going through Samsung Cloud). Here is how I imagine this:

1. You are outside somewhere and take some photos.
2. You come home and your Android connects to your home wifi.
3. Then an app or service wirelessly transfers the new photos to a folder on your laptop.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no on-board solution available. But with a little 3rd-party-help, this could be accomplished:

There's e.g. the app [PhotoBackup](https://f-droid.org/packages/fr.s13d.photobackup/) (also [available at Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.s13d.photobackup) if one insists) which does exactly that: automatically backup your photos as soon as they are taken – to your own backup server. For this it needs a counter-part on the server/computer you wish to backup to, which with this app is the tricky part (and [described on its homepage](https://photobackup.github.io/)).

Some alternatives can be found [in my app lists here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_1090).

A third one would be to self-build a solution with one of the [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) apps like [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) or [macrodroid](/questions/tagged/macrodroid): trigger a sync whenever a photo was taken. As I haven't done that, I cannot provide a recipe here.